# Painted and projected UVs not working as expected

Tags: uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor, project

Why are my strokes on Krita getting artifacts when I project them on this gun in Blender? P.s. It only happens with this part of the gun.

[image]

Comment: That looks like Z-fighting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting  Are you overlapping a plane on top of the existing faces? Please [edit] your question and add more detail on how you are creating the texture.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I moved the magazine and the side panels (which were overlapping each other) somewhere else and it works fine now, thanks!

Comment: Avoid overlapping faces, use textures instead. Read: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)